# Parallel computing efficiency - Number of cores or MPI processes?

Tags: parallel-processing, processing-efficiency

I'm testing a parallel program on a 2 + 2 (hyper threading) cores machine. The parallelization is effected through MPI routines.

While evaluating the efficiency of the parallel code, do I have to divide the speed up by the number of cores or the speed up by the number of MPI processes?

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please help!! I'm desperate!!! XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think correct answare is that p is always the number of processor/cores because the efficiency deacribes how your code's performances tend to the ideal values. So the genaral formula for the efficiency is

E=your_performance/best_performance

Best speed (ideal case) is the number of processors/cores p.

Answer (score 0):

Both make sense in some contexts, so it depends on what you want to measure.

For example, one could try running the program with 1, 2, 3, and 4 MPI processes and measure the speedup for each run. Then one could plot the measurements as a graph with the speedup on the y axis and the number of MPI processes on the x axis so illustrate the scalability (or non-scalability...) of the algorithm (under the assumption that using only e.g. two MPI processes would be the same thing as running the algorithm on a fully utilized computer with only two cores).

The same is true for efficiency.

But that kind of reasoning only works if the number of MPI processes are less then or equal to the number of physical cores you have. For example, if you try to use 5 MPI processes on your 4 core machine you would probably not get the same speedup as you would get on a 5 core machine, so that would therefore probably not measure what you want -- at least not for compute-bound problems.

The same is true, again, for efficiency.

So, if you have more MPI processes than physical cores then it only makes sense to talk about the speedup and efficiency with respect to the number of physical cores (at least as far as I can see). For example, continuing the 5 MPI processes on your 4 core machine example from above: assume that you get (only) somewhat improved speedup by using 5 MPI processes (e.g., because the MPI processes sometimes do blocking IO) compared to 4 MPI processes, then the efficiency with respect to the number of MPI processes would go down, but the efficiency with respect to the number of physical cores would go up. So in that case using 5 MPI processes would be better than 4, even if the efficiency with respect to the number of MPI processes would be lower (compared to using 4 MPI processes).

And of course, as usually, it would be easier to answer given more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for you help! :)
 I have built my parallel code to parallelize a Monte Carlo simaulation. I need to check performances of my code and i calculated the speed up factor measuring execution times of both sequential and parallel code for 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 MPI processes:

Speedup(#Processes) = time_sequential / time_parallel(#Processes)

Then i want to check that the fraction of non-parallelizable code (f) decrease for different workloads. To evaluate f i used the reverse Amdahl law:

f = (p - Speedup(p)) / (Speedup(p) * (p - 1))

to be continued...

Comment: After i want to evaluate efficiency through the formula:

Efficiency(p) = time_parallel(p) / p

I can't decide if p (for reverse Amdahl law and efficiency) is the number of precesses or the number of cores.

This is my problem! XD

Comment: I performed measurement on a cluster of PC connected by a network. The total number of cores is 32. In this case the problem doesn't exist because I measured execution time for different numbers of processes (always < 32). So I can check what solution (p=#Cores or p=#Processes) gives me the same fraction of non-parallizing code for tests on single machine and tests on cluster. The fraction of non-parallelizin code must remain the same for different workload. Is it right?

Comment: Sorry, it's still not entirely clear what you are asking. Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem is in the formula: 
Efficiency(p) = time_parallel(p) / p . 
"p" here is the number of MPI processes you execute it with. As mentioned by cic, it is the programmers reponsibility that he has sufficient cores to match number of MPI processes. To repeat, if you have only 2 cores and run with 5 MPI processes your efficiency results are wrong. Similarly if you have an 8 core machine and run your code with 2 MPI processes your "p" = 2

Comment: Thanks for your help! :) I think correct answare is that p is always the number of processor/cores because the efficiency deacribes how your code's performances tend to the ideal values. So the genaral formula for the efficiency is "E=your_performance/best_performance". Best speed (ideal case) is the number of processors/cores p. Do you agree?